# Aggregate 10 minute interval data to hourly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, data-cleaning

I have a df with Temperature and Humidity readings in 10-minute interval like:

```
Time                   
1/2/2017 13:00
1/2/2017 13:10
1/2/2017 13:20
1/2/2017 13:30
1/2/2017 13:40
1/2/2017 13:50
1/2/2017 14:00
1/2/2017 14:10
1/2/2017 14:20
```

I want to convert the df to hourly by taking the average within an hour:

```
Time
1/2/2017 13:00
1/2/2017 14:00
```

I tried groupby after converting to datetime:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df.groupby([times.hour, times.minute])
```

I got the error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'`

I tried

`df.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).hour).mean()`

but this grouped everything based on 24 hours of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked perfectly:
df.resample('60T').mean()

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = ['1/2/2017 13:00', '1/2/2017 13:10', '1/2/2017 13:20', 
         '1/2/2017 13:30', '1/2/2017 13:40', '1/2/2017 13:50',
         '1/2/2017 14:00', '1/2/2017 14:10', '1/2/2017 14:20']

numbers = np.random.randint(0, 11, 9)

df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, index=dates)

df
```

> 1/2/2017 13:00   5 
>   1/2/2017 13:10   8 
>   1/2/2017 13:20  10 
>   1/2/2017 13:30   1 
>   1/2/2017 13:40   6 
>   1/2/2017 13:50   7 
>   1/2/2017 14:00  10 
>   1/2/2017 14:10   7 
>   1/2/2017 14:20   8

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby(times.hour).mean()
```

> 13  6.166667 
>   14  8.333333

Here 13 and 14 represent the hourly aggregate, i.e., mean of 13h, mean of 14h.

Comment: Getting the error: 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'